# Как правильно пишется фраза «почему ? неизвестно»

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно пишется фраза «Почему ? неизвестно», где знак `?` обозначает место где, как мне кажется, может быть какой-то знак препинания?

- Земля вращается вокруг Солнца. Почему ? неизвестно.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Вместо "?" должно быть тире:

> Земля вращается вокруг Солнца. Почему — неизвестно.

Ещё примеры из прессы:

> [1.](http://plus-news.ru/fakty/item/8236-%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE.html) Янукович срочно собрал министров, почему — неизвестно.
>
> [2.](http://football.sport-express.ru/reviews/1757/) Арбитра поменяли в РФС. Почему — неизвестно.
>
> [3.](http://www.regnum.ru/news/483559.html) В Мурманске запретили купаться, но почему — неизвестно.